# Visualize Spark table joins and interactions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, visualization

I am new to Spark and dealing with huge and complex python scripts which use pySpark for data processing. I need to understand how each table is joined to another without spending days trying to understand the code.

I want to get UML-like diagram for the script I am stuck with ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRlBa.png)). How can I do this in a spark way?

I think about writing my own quick solution with parsing AST of given script or to decorate some of the spark functions with my own functions which will draw diagram during spark lazy phase when no data is being processed. Which one is better? Also, maybe I am missing something, how this type of problems is typically solved? For all I know, there is no way to do it using only spark package.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline, although it can be difficult to integrate it provides a runtime view over the programmatic flow.

Comment: It's definitely helpful, but I am looking for something simpler and more convenient to use as one time tool.